# Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'export'

Tags: reactjs

I have got this error `Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'export'` in my `react` project. When I try to export the `styles.js` to my main file. Below is the code for `styles.js`

```
    const export styles =  {
    border: 'solid',
    textAlign : 'center',
    boxShadow: '2px 2px'
  }
```

How to resolve this

Comment: in your code, it should be `export const styles = ...`

Comment: yeah got it thank you

Comment: Glad that you got it working now, I will flag it as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong words position.

```
export const styles = {}
```